# Python suds attirbuteError: Fault instance has no attribute 'detail'

Tags: python, oop, suds

Howdie do,

I've created a package class that sets some default values such as shipper, consignee, packages and commodities.

The issue is that when I go to call the method shippackage that is a suds client, I receive the error:

```
AttributeError: Fault instance has no attribute 'detail'
```

The first file listed below is my test file which sets the necessary dictionaries:

```
import ship

# Create a new package object
package1 = ship.Package('TX')

# Set consignee
package1.setconsignee('Dubs Enterprise', 'JW', '2175 14th Street', 'Troy', 'NY', '12180', 'USA')

# Set default packaging
package1.setdefaults('CUSTOM', '12/12/15', 'oktoleave')

# Add commodity description with each package
package1.addpackage('12.3 lbs', '124.00')
package1.addcommodity('This is package number 1', '23.5 lbs')

# Add commodity list to defaults dictionary
package1.setcommoditylist()

# Add package list to packages dictionary
package1.setpackagelist()
package1.shippackage()
```

The module that is being imported is the following:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.bindings import binding

binding.envns = ('SOAP-ENV', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope')
client = Client('http://localhost/ProgisticsAMP/amp.svc/wsdl', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'},
                faults=False)


class Package(object):

    def __init__(self, shipper):
        self.commoditylist = []
        self.commodityContents = {}
        self.consignee = {}
        self.defaults = {}
        self.packagelist = []
        self.packages = {}

        self.defaults['shipper'] = shipper

    def setconsignee(self, company, contact, address, city, state, zip, country):
        self.consignee['company'] = company
        self.consignee['contact'] = contact
        self.consignee['address1'] = address
        self.consignee['city'] = city
        self.consignee['stateProvince'] = state
        self.consignee['postalCode'] = zip
        self.consignee['countrySymbol'] = country

        self.defaults['consignee'] = self.consignee

    def setdefaults(self, packaging, shipdate, deliverymethod):
        self.defaults['packaging'] = packaging
        self.defaults['shipdate'] = shipdate
        self.defaults['deliveryMethod'] = deliverymethod

    def addcommodity(self, description, unitweight):
        commodity = {}
        commodity['description'] = description
        commodity['unitWeight'] = {'value': unitweight}

        self.commoditylist.append(commodity)

    def addpackage(self, weight, declarevalue):
        package = {}
        package['weight'] = {'value': weight}
        package['declaredValueAmount'] = {'amount': declarevalue, 'currency': 'USD'}
        self.packagelist.append(package)

    def setcommoditylist(self):
        self.commodityContents = {'item': self.commoditylist}

        self.defaults['commodityContents'] = self.commodityContents

    def setpackagelist(self):
        self.packages = {'item': self.packagelist}

    def shippackage(self):
        print self.defaults
        print self.packages

        # print client
        response = client.service.Ship('CONNECTSHIP_UPS.UPS.GND', self.defaults, self.packages, True, 'release')
        result = response.result
        print result
```

Within the shippackage method, I print self.packages and self.defaults and confirm that they have data within them before I call

```
client.service.Ship()
```

So I know it does have values within it before I call the client.service.Ship()

Am I missing something here? Why won't it take the defaults and packages dictionary that I've set?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the value 'shipdate'

The WSDL was expecting the shipdate in a different format.

The only way I was able to find this was switching my endpoint from SOAP 1.2 to 1.1

which I did by directly editing the web.config file

This is now 100% working